# Get updated HiddenField Value in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, hidden-field

I have a LinkButton in aspx page where on OnClientClick I am updating the value of Hidden Field, and on  OnClick I am saving that value to the database.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkUpdateGeocode" Text="Update Geocode"
OnClientClick="updateGeoCode()" OnClick="lnkUpdateGeocode_Click" />
```

where my **updateGeoCode()** function is

```
function updateGeoCode() {
        var address = document.getElementById('lblDisplayAddress');
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                longitudeField = $get('<%=Longitude.ClientID %>');
                latitudeField = $get('<%=Latitude.ClientID %>');

                longitudeField.value = longitude;
                latitudeField.value = latitude;
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful');
            }
        });
    };
```

and my **lnkUpdateGeocode_Click()** is

```
latitude = Latitude.Value.IsBlankOrNull() ? 0M : Convert.ToDecimal(Latitude.Value);
longitude = Longitude.Value.IsBlankOrNull() ? 0M : Convert.ToDecimal(Longitude.Value);
```

But I am always getting latitude and longitude values as 0.

So **My Question** is how to get the updated value of HiddenField in CodeBehind when I am changing that in javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

My HiddenField Value is set as runat="server"

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="Longitude" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="Latitude" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
```

I tried `Request.Form[Latitude.UniqueID]` but it is also giving Blank string.

[image]

Comment: Try removing EnableViewState="false" on hiddenfield

Comment: @RahulNikate I even tried that, but end up with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Set **runat="server"** attribute to your hidden field as shown below :

```
 <input type="hidden" value="" id="hiddenField" runat="server" />
```

Now you can directly access your hidden field value in your code behind :

```
var val = this.hiddenField.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are updating value in javascript. You have to access updated value using Request.Form.

You will get updated value in Request.Form.

```
string latitudeValue = Request.Form[Latitude.UniqueId];
```

Example :

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="1" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" OnClientClick="CallThis()">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CallThis() {
            $('#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val(100);
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply but no luck.

Comment: I have doubt that geocoder.geocode ajax call does not return and form get posted.

Comment: The value is updating in the javascript and after that only this method is getting called.