# how to determine which textbox is focused and add text to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating web application in asp.net. I have 5 text box which are asp controls. I want to get which text box having focus on that time and then when I am press "add" button, the "hello" text has to added to the particular text box which are got focused before pressed the "add" button.

I need Asp.net (with C# code) to move to my next step

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus

Answer (score 0):

Since the last focus will be on the Add button, you need to "remember" the TextBox before the Button is clicked.

Try to use onfocus() event.

```
<!-- Add a HiddenField control to "remember" the id of a TextBox -->
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />  

<!-- Assign current focus to that hidden field -->
<asp:TextBox onfocus="document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value=this.id" ...>
<asp:TextBox onfocus="document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value=this.id" ...>
```

If that works, you will be able to get a value in code-behind as

```
string c = HiddenField1.Value;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)) 
   if (c == "TextBox1")
      TextBox1.Text = "hi there";
```

Note: depends on your environment you might need to call ClientID (e.g. `getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>')`

**UPDATE**

As I told you above you might need to use HiddenField1.ClientID to find the HiddenField Control. When your source looks as

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$HiddenField1" id="MainContent_HiddenField1" /> 

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox1" type="text" id="MainContent_TextBox1" 
    onfocus="document.getElementById(&#39;HiddenField1&#39;).value=this.id" />    
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox2" type="text" id="MainContent_TextBox2" 
    onfocus="document.getElementById(&#39;HiddenField1&#39;).value=this.id" /> 

<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$Button1" value="Button" id="MainContent_Button1" />
```

That means that you use MasterPage and asp.net changes id of your control to `MainContent_HiddenField1`. So when you use `document.getElementById('HiddenField1')` it will not find such control because its id is different. You either need to use

```
document.getElementById('MainContent_Button1').value=this.id
```

which will work but might require changes if you remove master page or will move the textbox to other container

or use

```
document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value=this.id
```

which will automatically inject correct id (recommended asp.net way)

Comment: Thank  you.  while  I am try to use your code, It shows error like "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object". What to do ?

Comment: Did you try to change `getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>')` as suggested above? The error means that 'HiddenField1' cannot be found which means that asp.net dynamically changed it to some other id.

Comment: I tried "getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>')" also, same error getting

Comment: Open aspx page in the browser, right click, View Source. Copy and paste the html code related to HiddenField as well as TextBox controls here.

Comment: Its is not working in IE. But chrome it supporting. Thank  you.

Comment: I was select on text box and click add Button.  The   string c = HiddenField1.Value;  while tried to debug this line , the "c" value  show as "NULL" value.

Comment: It should work, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421475/get-updated-hiddenfield-value-in-code-behind It might be due to your page setup. I'd suggest to create a new simple aspx with only required controls and test.

Comment: I found the problem why  hidden value is not properly updated.  when i am using <asp:TextBox onfocus="doc..../>  code. The onfoucse funtion is not the property of Textbox.

Comment: I am using VS2010. What to do ?

Comment: "The onfoucse funtion is not the property of Textbox." -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: I am getting validation error "  onfocus is not a textbox property"

Comment: It's just a warning message in VS.NET, and not the error, isn't it? If you want to avoid that warning you could set onfocus from the code-behind using `TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value=this.id");`

Comment: I was added that code in page load. Still the variable C" value is Null only

Comment: Open aspx page in the browser, right click, View Source. Copy and paste the html code 1) related to HiddenField 2) as well as your TextBox controls here.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$HiddenField1" id="MainContent_HiddenField1" />  
    
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox1" type="text" id="MainContent_TextBox1" onfocus="document.getElementById(&#39;HiddenField1&#39;).value=this.id" />
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox2" type="text" id="MainContent_TextBox2" onfocus="document.getElementById(&#39;HiddenField1&#39;).value=this.id" />

    
 <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$Button1" value="Button" id="MainContent_Button1" />`

Comment: As I told you from the very beginning you should use ClientID property. See updated answer.